# Insert Check Box from Array Value on Change in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So, I'm running this code

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="bill[]" <?php if ($row['BillBack'] === '1') echo "checked"; ?>></td>
```

which creates a check box each time

```
while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {}
```

runs. So, right now it has 25 entries.
I want on submit button click, if the checkbox is checked to throw 1 into the database, and if it is not, to throw 0. Now, it seems the way to check if an array of check boxes is checked is with

```
foreach($_POST['bill'] as $selected){
echo $selected."</br>";
}
```

which, will return "on" for each one that is selected. BUT, my SQL has to look something like

```
"UPDATE Requests SET BillBack = '$bill' WHERE RequestID = $row['RequestID']"
```

so I assumed I needed to put the foreach loop inside of the while loop. But that returns 576 "on's"

Throwing an

```
(!isset($_POST['bill']))
```

into the while loop doesn't work, as it seems to be toggled if any of them are set, even though removing the ! only returns 24 "on's" (there is only one that is not toggled). so is there a way that while I still have the $row['RequestID'] to be able to check if each check box is set or not, and then throw it into my table while it is still associated with a $row?

Comment: not likely to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the $row["requestID"] as the value of the checkbox.  Then your bill[] will contain the requestID's you need.

For checkboxes, the contents of the value property do not appear in the user interface. The value property only has meaning when submitting a form. If a checkbox is in checked state when the form is submitted, the name of the checkbox is sent along with the value of the value property (if the checkbox is not checked, no information is sent).

IOW, all those unchecked checkboxes send nothing, so if only two are checked you will only have two items in your array.  Without a value, determining which two is impossible.

```
foreach ($bill as $id) {
  UPDATE Requests SET BillBack = '1' WHERE RequestID = $id;
}
```

And you can optimize that sql using "in" but I'm at work and don't have time